# jQuery UI tab - combination of tabs and onselect to go to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do I modify my javascript and HTML so that the first tab works as normal and the second tab directs my window to a completely new page?

I found this: http://snipplr.com/view/9513/, but could not figure out how to implement it.

My Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#tabs').tabs();      

    if($("#tabs") && document.location.hash){
        $.scrollTo("#tabs");
    }
    $("#tabs ul").localScroll({ 
        target:"#tabs",
        duration:0,
            hash:true
    });

    $('#tabs-min').tabs();

});
```

My HTML

```
<div id="tabs"><ul>
  <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="URL HERE" class="leave">Tab 2</a></li></ul>

  <div id="tab1">tab1 content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a fiddle up and running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Twawv/18/).  It doesn't totally work and I'm guessing it's because running a fiddle won't let you leave the fiddle (hence `window.location` not actually working), but you can see how it's done.  I've tested this code in my own environment and it does work.

You essentially add a class to the link you want to leave with (in my case, I've added the class `leave`).  Then, on beforeActivate, you check if the new tab's link has the class `leave` and if it does, head to it's link location.

Let me know if this works for you.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({

            beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {

                if (ui.newTab.find("a").hasClass("leave")) {

                     alert("leaving...");
                     window.location = ui.newTab.find("a").attr("href");
                     return false;
                }            
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="leave">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
       ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the class to the link and added the script and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Do I put your script after the existing script?

Comment: It should replace your `$("#tabs").tabs();`